# jqgrid: Datepicker widget as filter doesn't trigger filtering after close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid, datepicker

I tried using the datepicker with filter [based](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AshishBatra.htm) on this example.
Everything works fine, but the filter is not applied when the datepicker closes. I tried  triggerin the enter key event after closing the datepicker but it doesn't work (`$(elem).focus().trigger({ type: 'keypress', charCode: 13 });`). The only thing which triggers the filtering is changing the compare mode (==, !, ..).

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>jqgrid tests</title>
    <link href="js/jquery-ui-1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="js/multiselect-master/css/ui.multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="js/jquery.jqGrid-4.6.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="js/jquery.jqGrid-4.6.0/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.jqGrid-4.6.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.jqGrid-4.6.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        $(function () {
            var d = [
                    { id: "13", invdate: "2014-08-08T00:00:00", name: "test1", note: "note1", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true, ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                    { id: "1", invdate: "2012-09-16T00:00:00", name: "test1", note: "note1", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true, ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                    { id: "2", invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                    { id: "3", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
                    { id: "4", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test4", note: "note4", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true, ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                    { id: "5", invdate: "2007-10-31", name: "test5", note: "note5", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                    { id: "6", invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test6", note: "note6", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
                    { id: "7", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test7", note: "note7", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true, ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                    { id: "8", invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test8", note: "note8", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                    { id: "9", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test9", note: "note9", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "TN", total: "430.00" },
                    { id: "10", invdate: "2007-09-08", name: "test10", note: "note10", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: true, ship_via: "TN", total: "530.00" },
                    { id: "11", invdate: "2007-09-08", name: "test11", note: "note11", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" },
                    { id: "12", invdate: "2007-09-10", name: "test12", note: "note12", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" }
            ],
                $grid = $("#list"),
                initDateSearch = function (elem) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(elem).datepicker({
                            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                            autoSize: true,
                            changeYear: true,
                            changeMonth: true,
                            showWeek: true,
                            showButtonPanel: true,
                            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                                debugger;
                                $(elem).focus().trigger({ type: 'keypress', charCode: 13 });;
                            }
                        });
                    }, 100);
                },
                numberTemplate = {
                    formatter: "number", align: "right", sorttype: "number",
                    editrules: { number: true, required: true },
                    searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge", "nu", "nn", "in", "ni"] }
                };


            var $grid = $("#grid").jqGrid({
                datatype: "local",
                data: d,
                width: 800,
                //autowidth: true, 
                shrinkToFit: true,
                multipleSearch: true,
                colNames: ["Client", "Date", "Amount", "Tax", "Total", "Closed", "Shipped via", "Notes"],
                colModel: [
                    { name: "name", align: "center", editable: true, width: 65, editrules: { required: true } },
                    {
                        name: "invdate", width: 120, align: "center", sorttype: "date",
                        formatter: "date", formatoptions: { newformat: "Y-m-d" }, editable: true,
                        searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"], dataInit: initDateSearch }
                    },
                    { name: "amount", width: 75, editable: true, template: numberTemplate },
                    { name: "tax", width: 52, editable: true, template: numberTemplate },
                    { name: "total", width: 60, template: numberTemplate },
                    {
                        name: "closed", width: 70, align: "center", editable: true, formatter: "checkbox",
                        edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: { value: "Yes:No", defaultValue: "Yes" },
                        stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne"], value: ":Any;true:Yes;false:No" }
                    },
                    {
                        name: "ship_via", width: 105, align: "center", editable: true, formatter: "select",
                        edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:Intim", defaultValue: "IN" },
                        stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne"], value: ":Any;FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:IN" }
                    },
                    { name: "note", width: 60, sortable: false, editable: true, edittype: "textarea" }
                ],
                //sortname: "age",
                //sortorder: "desc",
                //ignoreCase: true,
                //height: "auto",
                //pager: '#pager',
                //rowNum: 10
                rowNum: 20,
                rowList: [5, 10, 20],
                multiselect: true,
                pager: '#pager',
                gridview: true,
                rownumbers: false,
                autoencode: true,
                ignoreCase: true,
                sortname: 'invdate',
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: 'desc',
                height: '100%',
                caption: 'Demonstrate how to use the columnChooser'
            })
            .jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {
                refreshstate: 'current',
                add: false,
                edit: false,
                del: false,
                search: true,
                refresh: false
            })

            .jqGrid("filterToolbar", { defaultSearch: "cn", searchOperators : true, searchOnEnter: false, stringResult: "true" })

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="grid"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
    <div id="pager"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

`JQGRID.triggerToolbar();` does the trick.

Full `onClose` Code:

```
onClose: function (selectedDate) {
    $grid[0].triggerToolbar();
}
```

DOKU: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching#using_the_additional_methods

> Using the additional methods
>
> The methods listed above should be used this way: ... var sgrid =
>   $("#grid_id")[0]; sgrid.triggerToolbar(); This will perform a search
>   dynamically.